# なしでは　なくしては　Difference

Tags: word-choice

How do I decide which of these to use in a given situation？

Answer (score 1):

I would say it’s safe to assume the difference is only in register. なくしては sounds formal and literary compared to なしでは and なしには, which are neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the word "なくしては" emphasizes the necessity/requirement of something, more than "なしでは".

I don't know if there is really a difference, but for example, let's say you have a sentence like this.

- "地図**なくしては**、この地域を旅する事はできないだろう。" → "*Without a map, it would be **impossible** to travel through this region.*"
- "地図**なしでは**、この地域を旅する事はできないだろう。" → "*Without a map, it would be **difficult** to travel through this region.*"

In other words, "なくして（は）" is an absolute requirement, but "なしで（は）" are necessary.

(Please keep in mind that this is just what I think it is, I don't know if it's really true)